# adding local .git via submodule failing

Tags: git

File structure:

```
www
 |- project
     |- .git
 |- dist
     |- .git
```

And the terminal:

```
karl@karl-laptop:~/www/project$ git submodule add ../dist dist
Cloning into 'dist'...
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'git@bitbucket.org:user/dist' into submodule path 'dist' failed
```

I'm having a hard time finding how to use submodule on local repos! As you can see it wants to clone from git@bitbucket, but I want it to clone from a local repo.

I normally use ssh to push to bitbucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters to `git submodule add` are `<repository>` and `<path>`, where `<repository>` is a reference to a "remote" repository and `<path>` is the relative path inside your current repository at which to install the submodule.

For example, if I am working in a directory `project1` that is a git repository and I want to add `../project2` as a submodule at `lib/project2`, I would run:

```
$ git submodule add ../project2 lib/project2
Cloning into 'lib/project2'...
done.
```

And now I can run `git submodule` to see the status of submodules:

```
$ git submodule
 2c1e66331909365e5c4d0f11659a1baeb863b3f0 lib/project2 (heads/master)
```

Comment: Added more relevant information, plus I tried your approach and still the same error :/

Comment: Iirc I had to remove all remote links to get it working as git on my machine and created a fresh got, it eventually worked.

Answer (score 1):

The git documentation says:

> git submodule add repository [path]
>
> repository is the URL of the new submodule’s origin repository. This may be either an *absolute* URL, or (if it begins with ./ or ../), the location relative to the superproject’s origin repository.

You need to specify an absolute file path if you want to clone from your file system. If you give `./` or `../` (as you do) it will attempt to fetch from the origin of the superproject, which is bitbucket.org in your case.